# Error IIS and Android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, iis

I'm Brazilian, and I apologize for my English, which is very bad

I've been facing a problem for some time, and I'm tired of looking for a solution in Portuguese.

I created a WCF service to be consumed by Android, hosted on a computer that I have at home with Windows server and iis installed, configured all the correct port releases for the application to work on the phone, but it has the following error in the execution: System.Reflection .TargetInvocationException

So I decided to host the WCF service on an external server, I used the number service. I just uploaded the files to it and changed the address references in the application to communicate with the WCF, and then it worked, so I guess some configuration that has to be done in IIS or in Windows itself, I'm waiting for some help. Thank you

Comment: You know there is a Portuguese version of Stack Overflow? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Yes I know, but I did not get answers